# Sonar, one profile for one project

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have different quality profiles and different projects. I would like to assign one profile to one project for example:

-quality_profile1 -> project1
-quality_profile2 -> project2
etc.

I don't know if it's possible and if it is I can't find where I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about it:

From the project level navigate to *(Project-level) Administration > Quality Profiles* and you'll have the per-language ability to associate specific profiles with the project. **You must have admin permissions on the project to do this.**

From the global level navigate to *Quality Profiles*, click on the name of the profile you'd like to assign and use the **Projects** part of the interface to assign one or more projects to the profile. **You must have the global Administer Quality Profiles permission to do this.**